# How to implement the frontend paging using Extjs 7.0

Tags: extjs

I know how to do it in the store with the backend paging. But would you please give the suggestions about how to do it with the frontend paging?

Comment: You mean, local pagination? Take a look at this example: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/pim&view/editor

Answer (score 0):

You can use a memory proxy and set the config property *enablePaging* to *true*.

Example:

```
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    autoLoad: true,
    pageSize: 5,
    data: data,
    proxy: {
        type: 'memory',
        enablePaging: true,
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            rootProperty: 'people'
        }
    }
});
```

I created a fiddle for this:
https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3c6e